# App Insights end to end times do not match

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to diagnose slow response times with our server. Currently I'm not getting useful information from app insights. An example is shown below. Total request duration is shown as 4.7s but you can see that end to end just doesn't give me any details as to why. I would expect the end to end steps to match with the duration.

Is there some configuration I'm missing out on here? If the slowness is not down to the database or any other dependency then it must be in the pipeline. It would be great to find out more information.

[image: Sample request]

Comment: i have similar behavior, adding a comment to follow it up.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am dealing with the exact same problem now...

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights tracks all kinds of Http calls, SQL calls ServiceBus and EventHubs .NET client SDK (depending on SDK version and flavor), it could be that your app makes calls it doesn't track: local IO, Redis, MongoDb, TCP WCF or TCP DocumentDb. We are working on extending the number of libs we collect calls from, but we don't collect everything.

It might be that the server is too slow because of CPU/mem/IO bottleneck and time is spent internally. Please check related metrics.

What kinds of external calls your app makes?

Comment: Hi Liudmila - Which metrics would you recommend to check the CPU bottleneck? On this particular request, the only dependency is with SQL Azure and a single call to blob storage. There seems to be over a 4 second delay from when the request was ingested into the API and any dependency telemetry logged. This makes things quite difficult to troubleshoot.